# how to change without a inner class?

Tags: java

I has a example like below. it uses two inner classes which has direct access to the methods and fields of its enclosing instance.Does it make sense not to use inner class? and how to modify it.

```
package java_example150;

public class TestThread3{
    private int j;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TestThread3 t = new TestThread3();
        Inc inc = t.new Inc();
        Dec dec = t.new Dec();

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
          Thread ts = new Thread(inc);
          ts.start();
          ts= new Thread(dec);
          ts.start();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void inc(){
        j++;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"-inc:"+j);
    }

    private synchronized void dec(){
        j--;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"-dec:"+j);
    }

    class Inc implements Runnable{
       public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
         inc();
        }
       }
    }

    class Dec implements Runnable{
         public void run(){
          for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
           dec();
          }
         }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example I don't think it is necessary to refactor it. You can leave it that way. Inner classes may be used when the are only necessary for one other class and they will only be access/instantiated by this class.

If you need the same functionality in another class, you can refactor it and move these classes in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

Threads need to have a `Runnable` type passed in as the thread's entry point. The inner classes are a fine way of doing this.

It might make sense (especially in this short example) to do it with anonymous classes. You can rewrite your loop like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    Thread ts = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) inc();
        }    
    );

    ts.start();
    ts= new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) dec();
        }    
    );
    ts.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happened when you tried to use a non-inner class? What difficulty are you trying to solve by avoiding an inner class?

You can convert to non-inner classes; you'll just have to pass the instance of TestThread3 to each object.

Comment: how to pass the instance of TestThread3 to each object?i am  confused.could you show me  the code?